# How to get html tag value inside an xml attribute value in java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, tags

I have an XML file whose lines are like these:

```
<row Id="1" PostId="" ..... Body="<p>....</p><p>...<a>....</p><p>....</p>"....>
```

I want to access the Body attribute. I used DOM parser, documentBuilder.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
Document doc = null;
try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        doc = dBuilder.parse(this.xmlFile);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
    for(int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++){
        Node n = nList.item(i);
        if(n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            NamedNodeMap nnmap = n.getAttributes();
            NodeList nnmapList = nnmap.getNamedItem("Body").getChildNodes()
            for(int k=0;k<nnmapList.getLength();k++){
                pr.write(k+": "+nnmapList.item(k).getTextContent()+ "\n");
            }
            pr.write("\n");
        }
    }
```

My output is like this:

```
0: <p>... <a href="...">...</a> ...</p><p>...</p>
```

Now I want to plain text in between the `<p>` and `<a>` tags. For `<a>`, I do not want the href, only link alias. How to achieve that in java?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is considered unstructured from the XML file's point of view (assuming XML files have points of view that is). In order to access tag contents you need to parse the HTML string separately. A framework often used for this is [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).